# Wiring Harness / Fuse Panel Repair

Tags: battery, wiring, fuse, fuse-panel

I have a 2006 Dodge Magnum and a friend of mine was changing the starter. Forgot to unhook the battery. And when the hot wire on starter grounded out it Melted the Negative battery cable until it caught fire.

We had an extinguisher and got it out quickly. The only visible damage i can find is the that the wiring under the fuse box melted due to the fire at the battery. i followed the wires and none of them melted further then 1 foot.

I am wondering if i could cut all the wires a foot or two back and put in a terminal plug like this:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Shakmods-24-pin-Female-ATX-EPS-Power-Connector-PSU-Socket-Black-24-Free-Pins-/171290945833

[image]

If you have a suggestion on better connector I am all ears.

To wire in a new Fuse Box without having to wire in a full new wiring harness.

Since the car was off What is the likelihood that no other electronics were affected.

By the way the fuse box and Battery are both in the Trunk of the Magnum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would get some insulated crimp butt connectors and a good quality crimp tool to ensure you get a good connection.  Ensure you use wire thick enough to match the existing wire.

Like these - http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/crimp-butt-splice-terminals/0534648/

[image]

and a tool similar to this - http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/cable-crimpers/4992313/

[image]

If you stagger them at different positions along the wires, you wont have a problem with a large bulge of connectors all totgether.

Alternatively if you are able, individually soldering and heat shrink insulating each wire will give the best possible connection.

Comment: I would be cutting the wire and tring to match up the existing wires from the Salvage Fuse box. I can solder and heat shrink if you think that would be best.   What is your opion on if other electronics might have been damaged?

Comment: I would recommend soldering if you are experienced, like in the top photo here - http://www.instructables.com/id/Master-a-perfect-inline-wire-splice-everytime/

Comment: If the ignition was off, my guess would be that everything else would be OK, but that is just a guess.